# Comparision of data available in one table using Select Query in asp

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, select, gridview

Respected all members, I have data for about two years in one SQL table and populated a gridview for this data (for one month) using Select query command as

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource15" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PunctualitymainConnectionString2 %>"  SelectCommand="SELECT SUM(case when Dir_Ind = 'Dir' then 1 else 0 end ) AS &quot;Direct&quot;, 

Rly FROM  PunctualityMain  

WHERE  Rly IN ('CR', 'ER', 'ECR', 'ECoR', 'NR', 'NCR', 'NER', 'NFR', 'NWR', 'SR', 'SCR', 'SER', 'SECR', 'SWR', 'WR', 'WCR') AND Date &gt;= '4/1/2012' AND Date &lt;= '4/30/2012'  

GROUP BY Rly"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The gridview is as

```
Rly  Direct
CR     5
ER     7
ECR    2
```

Now, I want to display this gridview as comparative statement (month compared with same month previous year) including %Improvement / Deterioration. Some thing like this

```
Rly    Current month Direct     Previous month Direct       %Improvement / Deterioration
CR         5                         8                           37.5
ER         7                         6                          -16.6
ECR        2                         2                            0.0
```

Is it possible? If yes, than please advise, how it can be achieved easily?

Comment: What I do in these type of scenario is: Getting data for both the months (i.e. current & previous) in separate columns in the query. (Using case when then statement). Then it becomes quite easy to bind the distributed columns to the GridView. Improvement & Deterioration columns could be calculated from .net code behind

Comment: Sir, can you write some code here for the solution as you advised above.

Comment: if you are still in need of the sample, i will post here but by night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon our above discussion, you may code your t-sql query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(case when Dir_Ind = 'Dir' and Date between '4/1/2012' and '4/30/2012' then 1 else 0 end ) AS 'CurrentDirect', 
       SUM(case when Dir_Ind = 'Dir' and Date between '3/1/2012' and '3/31/2012' then 1 else 0 end ) AS 'PreviousDirect', 
       Rly
FROM  PunctualityMain  
WHERE  Rly IN ('CR', 'ER', 'ECR', 'ECoR', 'NR', 'NCR', 'NER', 'NFR', 'NWR', 'SR', 'SCR', 'SER', 'SECR', 'SWR', 'WR', 'WCR') 
 AND Date >= '3/1/2012' AND Date <= '4/30/2012'
GROUP BY Rly
```

This way you may set the datasource of GridView to the resulted output. You may calculate the improvement and deterioration column in the t-sql or in the GridView's RowDataBound event.

Comment: Its working. Thanks. One more thaing.. can it be used with select parameters also?

Comment: You're welcome. Obviously. For e.g., in this sample you might add CurDateFrom, CurDateTo, PrevDateFrom, PrevDateTo parameters to the command object. Moreover, you can make the PrevDateFrom and PrevDateTo based upon CurDateFrom and CurDateTo values provided by the user.

Comment: For an example to add SelectParameters to your data source refer to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters.aspx